# How do I make a self reference in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, poco

I have a device class,  computer class and a virtualdesktop class.  Every computer is a device and every virtualdesktop is a computer.   I want to add a property to my virtualdesktop that references another device of type computer indicating where the virtual device is hosted.  I am using POCOs with Entity Framework 5.0 in a Code First environment.  How should I add this property to my virtualdesktop class below ?  Is this a self-referencing relationship ?

```
[Table("devices")]
public class device 
{
   public int DeviceId { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}

[Table("computers")]
public class computer : device
{
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public string OS_LicenseKey { get; set; }
}

[Table("virtualdesktops")]
public class virtualdesktop : computer
{
 //Should I do this
  public Computer Computer {get; set;}

 //Or should I do this
  public int ComputerId {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need both.

Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code) for more details including how to set up optional and many to one relationships.